# Современная грамотная речь: глаголы "сказать" и "рассказать"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему некоторые, рассказывая о чем-то, не говорят: он сказал(а) о том-то или о чем-то, а говорят:  он мне рассказал то, что...

Может, правила русского языка поменялись или это я туплю?

Comment: Тупить, воздействуя  на инструмент, может неподдающийся ему материал. Человек тупеет.

Comment: Тупить, несов. неперех. значение: (о человеке) медленно соображать, не делать чего-либо простого, не понимать, как это делается. Молодежный сленг.

Comment: Входя в приличную компанию, обычно оставляют сленг за дверью.

Answer (score 3):

Он ***рассказал*** (сказал), что долго не мог найти места, где стоял его дом, всё изрыто окопами, воронка на воронке, черепки да ямы. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)]

Он ***сказал***, что при проектировании дома была допущена ошибка. [Владимир Войнович. (1976)]

**Глаголы различаются обычно по объему информации**, ***рассказать*** используется для более содержательного и подробного рассказа.

Как видно из приведенных примеров, глагол ***сказать*** иногда может заменить глагол ***рассказать***, но не наоборот. В случае краткого сообщения нужно использовать глагол ***сказать***. Нельзя говорить: ***он рассказал, что приедет завтра.***

**Это неправильная современная речь**.

Интересно, что раньше глагол ***сказать*** мог обозначать **подробный рассказ**.

Из словаря:  Устар. и разг. Рассказать. **Бабушка, скажи нам сказку!** С. ли тебе, как я живу? Ну-ка, Люба, скажи нам стихотворение! (расскажи, прочитай наизусть). Красота-то какая - и не с. Ни в сказке с., ни пером описать (нар.-поэт.; о чём-л. очень хорошем, прекрасном.